# How To Get Real Download / Upload Speeds

Tags: download, modem, upload, internet-speed

So When I Download or Upload I know I'm not getting the correct Upload / Download speeds that any Speedtest says I should get. What are could be some reasons behind this that I could check? I have a normal Charter Modem and have a Wireless Netgear Router. My computer that I am checking the Up/Down is wired directly into the Wireless Router (Not picking up internet wirelessly). What could be slowing down my speeds?

Comment: How do you know exactly?  My guess your router doesn't have a GB lan port like your computer does

Comment: @Ramhound I thought that MBps == MB/s - as I wasn't uploading or downloading at a MB/s speed.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you just aren't converting your units correctly. For example, if Speedtest says you should have a line speed of 1 Mbps, that's equal to a download speed of 122 KB/s. There are 1,024 bytes in a kilobyte and 8 bits in a byte. Line speeds are measured using decimal units and in bits. Download speeds are measured using binary units and in bytes.

Comment: I guess i'm pretty ignorant on the subject, so what you're saying is 1MBps Line Speed does not mean I'm able to download 1 Megabyte Per Second?

Comment: No, it does not. Mbps and MB/s are totally different units that measure different things.

Answer (score 1):

Many things are Involved in Internet Download and Upload Speed. Also there are many process that are using Internet (Like sending data and etc.), so How much they uses net , the same speed of Bandwidth are blocked by them.
First step is that you have to see Which process and How they are using Network. so you can use a Windows Built-in application that called "Resource Monitor". its a simple program and have the enough usage (But if you are a Advanced user, you may want to test other programs).
Open your Resource Monitor (Using Performance Tab in Task Manager and start that, or typing resmon.exe in your RUN program.).go to Network tab. Now you can see which process are using the Network and how much data they are using from your internet. All of these process are involved in your Network and Internet Speed.
So you can Stop the process you EXACTLY know that what they are doing (Or else, it is not Recomended).

Now you know what process are using your Internet without your knowledge.

 Now its the time to test your Really Internet Speed.

This utility is a one of the greatest utilities that can show you, your really internet speed, it called [Terminal Speedtest](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tespeed/) (for Linux users)
Also you can use this [Tespeed](https://github.com/Janhouse/tespeed) . (Its working with Python, so you can search and find out that how you can use the Python scripts)
One of the other websites you can test your Internet speed is [Speepeedtest](http://speedtest.net) service.

Answer (score 1):

If speedtest.net is showing you the expected results then the issue is most likely not on your network. However, the sites you visit or the content you download could be the issue. Sites, much like your own network, have a upload and download speed.

If you're visiting a site that is hosted in someone's basement like most of mine then your download will be limited to my upload speed.

If the content you're downloading is several small files, then you're probably not going to get your quoted rate as that is typically a burst rate.

Answer (score 0):

The following things can slow down your Internet speed:

1. Background applications
2. Some kind of Trojan
3. And maybe your Internet speed is not "Constant", at night I have 5mpbs download, at day 2 - 3 mbps ... Because ISP is sharing speed by "needs" :)